# How I make the function to know this in class without pass the this in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I using typescript.

When I run this code I get `undefined` in `this`.

Is there another ways to make `foo` to know about `this` besides than: `bind`, or pass `this` to the function?

```
function foo(o) {
  console.log({ that: this }); //undefined.
}

class Foo {
  xxx = foo({
    x:1     
  });
}
```

Comment: You may specify this type for foo as first parameter type like this: ```foo(this: Foo, o)```.

Comment: "besides than: bind, or pass this to the function"

Comment: What for you're looking for an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the type a function expects `this` to be with `this: TypeHere` as the first argument.

In your case, that may look like:

```
interface MyThis { prop: number }
function foo(this: MyThis) { /*...*/ }
```

Now typescript will only let you call this function if `this` is the expected type.

```
foo.apply({ prop: 123 }) // works
foo.apply({ someProp: 'whatever' }) // type error
```

To use a method like this in a class, you need to make an interface that a class can implement, which satisfies the needs of the function.

```
interface MyThis { prop: number }

function foo(this: MyThis) {
  console.log(this.prop); // number
}

class Foo implements MyThis {
  // Implement the required interface
  prop: number = 123
  
  // Use `foo` in this class.
  fooMethod = foo
}

new Foo().fooMethod() // works!
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8AqALYBnZAb2QAcoB7EgLmRAFcBbAI2mQF8AoDmOkBMYORDIY5cgAowuPDQw58ASiIdkyBELzkANhAB0W8gHNJ03WUoKA3MgD0N2oxZQOnDgi1w8BAGJjkwBhIdBghwAjlpZVVzagdmVgBeZABGACYAZhVkLLtkAFU8FAADUXIi-2F3TzwAGmQiqXxykHIAd2QGODAEbAgCUGQpFCqvZDgQABMK+tKi3SzS1Agpcimk0pcuXNbyKABrPHmQCHbfCQVdReXsVfEFbjFdOBIg9HFCGJoAFgBWADY2PcOLkIAAPEgQfgQKbQChQAgsBBwOiFeqNPDlfC0chgQa9NS7KCQ3FgdAQ+alO4PchPF5aN6ETQhAAKFFiAHIWri4GgsNJ2YCgA)